# Node & Yarn Command Means

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

I am trying to found

```
npm run install:global
npm install -g win-node-env
yarn && npm run dev:build && npm run dev:serve
```

What does this three command means ?
I tried to search google but not got relative info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any extra info...

### 1:

`npm run` runs the next argument defined in the "scripts" property of your `package.json` file.  So, `npm run install:global` will execute whatever the corresponding script entry by that name. If your `package.json` file has this entry (and it should):

package.json:

`"scripts": {
    "install:global": "npm install -g whatever-the-script-is"
}`

### 2:

`npm install -g win-node-env` will globally install the win-node-env package, so that it's accessible from a terminal session by typing whatever `win-node-env` exposes.

### 3:

`yarn && npm run dev:build && npm run dev:serve`

Yarn is an alternative for npm.  This command would run `yarn`, then the script in `package.json` that correspond to `dev:build` and immediately after run `dev:serve`.

Answer (score 1):

> `npm run install:global`

Run specified npm script

> `npm install -g win-node-env`

Install package globally

> `yarn && npm run dev:build && npm run dev:serve`
>   same as 
>   `npm install && npm run dev:build && npm run dev:serve`

Install local packages and run script

This is how package.json might look like

```
{
  "name": "demo"
  "scripts": {
    "install:global": "npm install -g my-unrealistic-package"
    "dev:build": "echo \"build something\"",
    "dev:serve": "echo \"serve something\""
  }
}
```